# how to post data without special characters and without using regex

Tags: javascript, php

I am posting form data to php file and then storing it in database. I am using serialize method to serialize form data. It serialize data like:

```
date=1%2BF%2+-+1%2BF%2&selValue0%2B%C=23
```

but I want to post it like:

```
date =12-12&selValue0=23
```

I have tried `unserialize()` in php , url encoding decoding in javascript and php but not working

Comment: If you're POSTing the data, why don't you use `$_POST['date']` and `$_POST['selValue']`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="date" />
<input type="text" name="setValue0" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
echo @file_get_contents('php://input');
?>
```